# How to handle an exception in Django moving from get() to filter()

Tags: django

original code with get()

```
    try:
        record = Record.objects.get(name__iexact=record_name)
    except Record.DoesNotExist:
        logging.debug("Error: Record does not exist")
        return Response({"Error": "Record does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

This query can return more than one record, so I am going to switch to this

```
    try:
        record = Record.objects.filter(name__iexact=record_name)[0]
    except Record.DoesNotExist:
        logging.debug("Error: Record does not exist")
        return Response({"Error": "Record does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

However, then my exception handling doesn't work.  How do I make my exception catch if the query returns an empty list?

Answer (score 5):

`filter()` not raise `DoesNotExist` error. You can catch `IndexError` to prevent error in case queryset is empty and doesn't contain any elements:

```
try:
    record = Record.objects.filter(name__iexact=record_name)[0]
except IndexError:
    logging.debug("Error: Record does not exist")
    return Response({"Error": "Record does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Or you can use `first()` method, which also not raise error. But you can check result with `if` statement:

```
record = Record.objects.filter(name__iexact=record_name).first()
if not record:
    logging.debug("Error: Record does not exist")
    return Response({"Error": "Record does not exist"},
```

Answer (score 3):

You might prefer to use [`first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```
record = Record.objects.filter(name__iexact=record_name).first()
if record is None:
    # record does not exist - handle this
```

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or `None` if there is no matching object.  If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Use the powers bestowed on you by the queryset API:

```
record_qs = Record.objects.filter(name__iexact=record_name)
if not record_qs.exists():
    logging.debug("Error: Record does not exist")
    return Response({"Error": "Record does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
else:
    record = record_qs[0]
    # Do stuff with record.
```

Comment: You are making two queries here. Better use first()  and then check if the object is not None